# How do you change a value in a cell from python to excel with the insert python in the new beta channel of Microsoft insider?

Tags: python, excel

I just started with python in excel (the insider beta channel of Microsoft office) and I get how to get a value in a cell into python, but I can't get how to do the opposite: put a value from python into a cell.

Comment: (Assuming u didn't want to use the conventional python write to xlsx function library..)  Will [ 'produce value > put in clipboard > (using pyautogui, with excel active) invoke Ctrl+G,type'A1','enter',Ctrl+V ] do ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for.

if you use the =py( to enter python mode in cell A1 and enter:

```
x = 10
y = 20
x*y
```

cell A1 will return 200. **Note you don't need any `return` or `print`.**

Now, if you use the =py( to enter python mode in cell A2 and enter:

```
x = xl("A1")
y = 1
x+y
```

cell A2 will return 201.

**P.S.** I also tried possibility on iterating but seems like excel is returning some object instead of string

at cell A3 with python mode:

```
a = "A"
num= "1"
a + num
```

shows A1 at the cell A3 but the value cannot be read as string "A1" from another cell by either `xl(xl("A3"))` or `xl(str(xl("A3")))`

Guess would need to wait for more documentations to be released from microsoft.